# echo CHILD / SUB CATEGORIES of the CURRENT CATEGORY only

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo all CHILD / SUB CATEGORIES of the CURRENT CATEGORY only. This is my code, but it's displaying all child categories no matter what parent category we are on. I only need this to show the sub cats of the parent category, in my custom taxonomy.

I have tried changing this:

```
'parent' => 0,
```

with no luck.

```
<?php
    $taxonomyName = "cosmetics";
    $parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));   
    echo '<div style="height: 200px; text-transform: uppercase; border:1px solid #666666; padding:10px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="breaker-small">Refine Search</div>';
    foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo '<p class="filters"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></p>';  
        }
    }
    echo '</div>
    <br />';

    ?>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code loops through *all* top level categories, then shows all child categories of each one, so I'm not surprised it's showing all child cats!

If you want to show the child terms of the *current* category (i.e. on a category archive?), use:

```
$current_cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
$kids = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy,
    'parent'   => $current_cat_id,
]);
```

And as a complete answer:

```
<?php

$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy,
    'parent'   => get_queried_object_id(),
]);

echo '<div style="height: 200px; text-transform: uppercase; border:1px solid #666666; padding:10px; overflow-y: scroll;">
<div class="breaker-small">Refine Search</div>';
foreach ( $terms as $term) {
    echo '<p class="filters"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></p>';  
}
echo '</div>
<br />';

?>
```

Comment: You're new to PHP aren't you. Here ya go.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working